# Loading Blacklist of IPs from a file into IPTABLES

Tags: iptables, bash, sed

In a separate file I'm creating a list of IP addresses to be blocked. This file will have IPs added in or removed on a daily basis. I want to "reference" this IP File into /etc/sysconfig/iptables, but I'm not sure if that is possible. If yes, please describe how to do that (ie: ExternalList=/var/tmp/myblacklist.txt) ???

If that type of reference isn't possible in IPTABLES, what would be a good script to add entries from myblacklist.txt into iptables and remove entries from iptables which no longer appear in the myblacklist.txt file?

I'm honestly looking for a simple bash script that might utilize sed. Otherwise, I think I'll trend down the road of putting all the IPs I want to allow/block into an MySQL table and just setting up a script to compile a new iptable on a daily basis. This way mods can be done in the sql DB and the iptables will just print whatever is in the DB. But before I choose that option, could I get away with some simple bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should investigate using the ipset module for this:

http://ipset.netfilter.org/

Simply add all the IP addresses into a set, and then setup a single iptables rule which drops/rejects packets against that set.

Also easy to manage as you can add, remove and empty the set easily, and generally modify it "on the fly", as and when required.